# C# EF how to include entity that already used as child List<>

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, migration

I'm new to EF, and I'm little confused..

I have these entities:

```
class Employee
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string? Login { get; set; }
    
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    public string? MidName { get; set; }
    
    public Guid? DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public Department? Department { get; set; }
    
    public Guid? OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public Organization? Organization { get; set; }
    
    public Guid? StateId { get; set; }
    public State? State { get; set; }
}

class Department
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? ShortName { get; set; }

    public Guid? ParentDepartmentId { get; set; }
    public Department? ParentDepartment { get; set; }

    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; } = new();
    
    public Guid ManagerID { get; set; }
    public Employee Manager { get; set; }

    public Guid? StateId { get; set; }
    public State? State { get; set; }
}
```

Now I can't add a migration because of `Manager` property and got this error message:

> Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type 'BlazorTest.Components.Data.DataContext'. The exception 'Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Department.Employees' of type 'List'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'

How to deal with this situation? Thank you in advance!

Tried many variations of fluentApi code, but since I'm new to EF I got stuck...

I use PostgresSQL

p.s. sorry for bothering with such question, but I'm just 2 weeks in it...

Answer (score 0):

Two things: EF can work out relationships by convention, but defaults to resolving FK properties based on Type name, not property name. I recommend always using `[ForeignKey]` Attributes to ensure that EF uses the expected values where FK properties are present:

```
public Guid? ParentDepartmentId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey(nameof(ParentDepartmentId))]
public Department? ParentDepartment { get; set; }

public Guid ManagerID { get; set; }
[ForeignKey(nameof(ManagerID))]
public Employee Manager { get; set; }
```

Next, you have two relationships between Employee and Department, a one to many (Department.Employees / Employee.Department) and what would likely be a one-to-one. (Department.Manager)  The issue is that EF won't know if Employee.Department belongs to the other side of the Department.Employees or Department.Manager so you need to explicitly configure that. If you have an `IEntityTypeConfiguration` implementation or `OnModelCreating` implemented then you can do it there by setting up the `.HasMany(x => x.Employees).WithOne(x => x.Department)` on the Department configuration, or use an `[InverseProperty]`:

```
[InverseProperty(nameof(Employee.Department))]
public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; } = new();
```

... and that should keep EF happy.